# Executing a dynamic query inside a CROSS APPLY statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given:

- *@Records* holds a list of integer ID's
- *#Columns* contains information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for more than one table (and some other stuff)

I'm trying to cycle through the @Records and pivot the column values into a backup table. For example:

```
DECLARE @KeyId
SET @KeyId = 1
DECLARE @Records (id int)
INSERT INTO @Records VALUES (1),(2),(3)

DECLARE #Columns (ColName varchar(100),ColType varchar(100),DataTable varchar(100),DataSchema(100))
INSERT INTO #Columns (ColName,ColType,DataTable,DataSchema) VALUES
('Column1','int','Table1','dbo.'),
('Column2','varchar(50)','Table1','dbo.'),
('Column3','varchar(10)','Table2','dbo.'),
('Column3','int','Table2','dbo.')

CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int, Column1 int, Column2 varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE Table2 (id int, Column3 varchar(10), Column4 int)

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1,1,'test1'),(2,2,'test2')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,'test3',3),(2,'test4',4)
```

---

Should pivot from

```
Table1                  Table2
id|Column1|Column2      id|Column3|Column4
__________________      __________________
1 |1      |'test1'      1 |'test3'|3
2 |2      |'test2'      2 |'test4'|4
```

into

```
 KeyId|ColName  |ColValue|DataTable|DataSchema
_______________________________________________
     1|'Column1'|'1'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column2'|'test1' |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column3'|'test3' |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column4'|'3'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column1'|'2'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column2'|'test2' |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column3'|'test4' |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column4'|'4'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
```

---

```
DECLARE @r int
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Records)
BEGIN
    SET @r = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Records)
    SELECT @KeyId,col.ColName,colValue,col.ColType,col.DataTable,col.DataSchema
    FROM #Columns col
        CROSS APPLY(
            EXEC ('SELECT '+col.ColName+' FROM '+col.DataSchema+col.DataTable+' WHERE '+'Id'+' = '+@r)
        ) x(colValue)
    DELETE TOP(1) FROM @Records
    @KeyId += 1
END
```

Unfortunately the 'EXEC [...]' statement is apparently not allowed in that context (which I suppose is reasonable). However, something like

```
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT '1'
)
```

gives

```
     KeyId|ColName  |ColValue|DataTable|DataSchema
_______________________________________________
     1|'Column1'|'1'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column2'|'1'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column3'|'1'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     1|'Column4'|'1'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column1'|'1'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column2'|'1'     |'Table1' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column3'|'1'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
     2|'Column4'|'1'     |'Table2' |'dbo.'|
```

Formats exactly how I would like, except with a '1' instead of the value I need.

Is there some approach I can take to do the same sort of:

```
For each @Record
    For each col.DataTable
        For each col.ColName
            get the Column value
```

or a way to execute a dynamic select in that spot?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do (hint:  sample data, desired results).  But you cannot have part of a query be dynamic.  All or nothing.

Comment: I've added a sample and desired output to the question.